# C# - Split a string separated by ':'

Tags: c#

Im trying to split this string:

```
PublishDate: "2011-03-18T11:08:07.983"
```

I tried Split method but it's not successful.

```cs
str.Split(new[] { ':', ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

As a result I get `PublishDate` `2011-03-18T11` `08` `07.983`

But correct result is `PublishDate` `2011-03-18T11:08:07.983`

What i need to do?

Comment: What is expected result for you

Comment: this seems to come from a json, this sounds like a [X/Y problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). You'd be better parsing correctly the data you have as input. Otherwise, a simple regex would work or replace with string.

Comment: @Qwerty it is already written in the question.

Comment: Replace `new[] { ':', ' ' }` with the string literal `": "` and it'll work

Comment: @Qwerty "correct result" is printed explicitly in the question.  I assume that's what's expected.  Although, splitting a string on `:` and *not* expecting it to be split where the colon is -- is asking for magic.

Comment: note that what's written in the question is inconsistent with the code: some double quotes `"` should still be in your current result (I think current output is actually `PublishDate` `"2011-03-18T11` `08` `07.983"`).

Comment: I think you are looking for `Replace()` 
function `str.Replace("PublishDate: ","").Replace("\"","")`

Comment: Why don't you just parse this as a normal `DateTime` and then work on that value

Comment: @Pac0 JSON would require that the property name be quoted.  `{ "PublishDate": "2011-03-18T11:08:07.983" }`

Comment: @Pac0 nvmd the braces, without the quoted parameter it's invalid JSON still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Split(String, Int32, StringSplitOptions)
```

Splits a string into a maximum number of substrings based on a specified delimiting string and, optionally, options.

```
str.Split(':', 2,   StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-6.0#system-string-split(system-string-system-int32-system-stringsplitoptions)

Answer (score 0):

I would solve like this:

- locate the index of the first `:`.  The property name will be all the characters before this, which you can extract with Substring and Trim to remove whitespace before the colon, if present.
- locate the index of the first `"` and last `"`.  Characters between the first and last quotes are the property value.

```cs
string input = "PublishDate: \"2011-03-18T11:08:07.983\"";

int iColon = input.IndexOf(':');
int iOpenQuote = input.IndexOf('"', iColon);
int iCloseQuote = input.LastIndexOf('"');
string propertyName = input.Substring(0, iColon).Trim();
string propertyValue = input.Substring(iOpenQuote + 1, iCloseQuote - iOpenQuote - 1);
```

This does not handle escaped characters within the property value (for example, to embed a literal quote or newline using a typical escape sequence like `\"` or `\n`).  But it's likely good enough to extract a date/time string, and permits all characters because of the use of LastIndexOf.  However, this is not robust against malformed input, so you will want to add checks for missing colon, or missing quote, or what happens when the close quote is missing (same same index for start and end quote).

Answer (score 0):

So if I got you right, you want as a result: PublishDate 2011-03-18T11:08:07.983.

Then I would recommend you to use the string.Replace method.

```
using System;

public class HelloWorld
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string yourData = "PublishDate: \"2011-03-18T11:08:07.983\"";
        
        // First replace the colon and the space after the PublishDate with and space
        // then replace the quotes from the timestamp -> "2011-03-18T11:08:07.983"
        yourData = yourData.Replace(": ", " ").Replace("\"", "");
        
        // Output the result -> PublishDate 2011-03-18T11:08:07.983
        Console.WriteLine(yourData);
    }
}
```